# Proving that $\frac{\pi ^2}{p}\neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{a_{n}^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

we have many formula for $\pi ^2$ as follow $$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}....$$
and $$\frac{\pi ^2}{8}=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}....$$ and for $\frac{\pi ^2}{9}$, $\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$, $\frac{\pi ^2}{16}$,$\frac{\pi ^2}{24}$.. and so on. If you see the number in denominator is not prime.Now we want to prove that
  $$\frac{\pi ^2}{p}\neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{a_{n}^2}$$ Where $p$ is a prime number and $a_{n}$ a positive integer number

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: What are the $a(n)$? Are you asking to prove that no sequence of positive integers can have this as result?

Comment: If the denominators are distinct, $\pi^2/10$ through $\pi^2/15$ are all impossible.

Comment: You should a) add the clarification that the denominators are distinct and b) link to your last question (that _was_ you, right?).

Comment: `[Related Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007424/166353)` gives [Related Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007424/166353)

Comment: See Micah's answer to the other question; the claim is not true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to put any restrictions on the $a_n$, there is no number theory here, only analysis. If I may quote from [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1007730/30836):

> **Theorem**: Let $\sum_k s_k$ be a convergent sum of positive numbers, say $S=\sum_k s_k$. Suppose that, for all $n$, we have $s_n < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty s_k$. Then there is a subsequence of $s_k$ whose sum converges to $x$ for any positive $x < S$.

Intuitively, say we're trying to construct a subsequence. The sum is convergent, so its terms must become arbitrarily small and thus allow us to approach $x$ arbitrarily closely. The only thing that can go wrong is that at some point all the  terms we have left aren't big enough to get us to $x$. The condition $s_n < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty s_k$ ensures that, whenever this happens, we'll have room to use the earlier term $s_n$ without exceeding $x$, and so the only way we can't get to $x$ is if we were already using all the earlier terms (i.e., $x>S$).

The series $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ satisfies the hypotheses of this theorem, and so we can write *any* number less than $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$ as a sum of the reciprocals of distinct squares (with $a_1>1$). Similarly, if $1 < x < \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we can write $x-1$ as a sum of the reciprocals of distinct squares, and then throw in a $1$ at the beginning to get such a representation for $x$ (with $a_1=1$).

In particular, if $p$ is prime, $\frac{\pi^2}{p}$ can be written in the form you want unless $p \in \{2,3,5,11,13\}$. But **that has nothing to do with their primality**: it's all about the gross size of $\frac{\pi^2}{p}$.

The interesting number theory happens when you put further conditions on the $a_n$, such as [requiring them to be in arithmetic progression...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function)

Answer (score 3):

I ran the greedy algorithm from the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007424/166353) for the first 1000 primes with the added caveat that the terms in the sequence have to be distinct. It appears that your statement is only true for the primes 2, 3, 5, 11, 13 and false for the rest! I've only used 40 terms in the algorithm for each of the primes. For those that work, the accuracy is quite good (hundreds of digits for the larger primes). For example if $A_p$ stands for the terms for prime p then

$$A_7 = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 11, 42, 991, 59880, 21165404, 81090759408,\ldots \}$$

and if $S_p(n)$ stands for the partial sum we have

$$S_7(10) = \frac{9409086091684410250487330038662170074145032522104397}{66733781786148561048500788381308231
   67971682291718400} $$

with

$$\frac{\pi^2}{7}- S_7(10) \approx 3.0292 \cdot 10^{-34}$$

**EDIT**: I ran the algorithm again but this time with the integers from 1 to 100 because I suspected the problem is not just with the primes themselves. The algorithm failed to converge within 15 terms for the numbers

$$E = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15\}$$

The algorithm is way off for these integers. I'm willing to conjecture that for every integer $k\notin E$ there exists a sequence of positive integers $a_{n,k}$ such that

$$\frac{\pi^2}{k} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n,k}^2}$$

Comment: You are absolutely right. My code was off!

Comment: I was able to produce the same list of numbers as you. The question is why should those lead to a failure? Can one apply the theorem you wrote out?

Comment: Yes. Those are the numbers $n$ such that either $\frac{\pi^2}{n} > \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (so there's no hope) or $1 > \frac{\pi^2}{n} > \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1$ (so we can't include the first term, and there's no hope without it). The theorem applies to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ starting with the second term, so those are the only ways anything can go wrong.

Comment: By the greedyness of the algorithm,the error of the partial sum after adding $\frac1{n^2}$ is known to be less than $\frac1{(n-1)^2}-\frac1{n^2}\approx\frac3{n^3}$. For your example, this estimate gives $\approx 5.6\cdot 10^{-33}$, not much larger than  the actual error.