# Can every positive real number $\leqslant\frac{\pi^2}6$ be expressed in this form?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For an arbitrary $0\leqslant x \leq\frac{\pi^2}6$, can we write $x$ in the form
$$
x = x_0+\sum_{j\in S\subset\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}} \frac1{j^2}, \tag 1 
$$

where $x_0\in\{0,1\}$.

My motivation is this: Let $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\mathrm{Ber}(p)$, $Y_n = \frac{X_n}{n^2}$, and $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n Y_k$. Then $S_n$ converges weakly to some random variable $S$. I would like to know whether $S$ is continuous, i.e. takes all values over $\left[0,\frac{\pi^2}6\right)$, or if $S$ is discrete (takes values in some countable subset of $\left[0,\frac{\pi^2}6\right)$). The former is true if the representation of elements of $\mathbb R$ described in (1) is correct, and the latter is true if not. Note that $\mathbb P(Y\leqslant \frac{\pi^2}6)=1$ because $Y\leqslant\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$ a.s.

My gut feeling is that $S$ is discrete, as there will be values $\frac jk$ which cannot be obtained by finite sums of elements of $\{\frac1{m^2}:m=1,2,\ldots n\}$ no matter how large $n$ is. But I do not know how to show this rigorously. Advice on how to show this, and hints what the distribution of $S$ looks like would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm rather confused by your question; your sum evaluates to $2^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{j^2}$. Are you sure you don't want $x=\sum_{j\in S}\frac{1}{j^2}$ where the variable we control is that $S$ is some subset of $\mathbb N$? Also, if you restrict $S$ to be a finite set, the sum could clearly only take on countably many values, since there are only countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ - but this would have little to do with what values $S$ could take - and even if we don't, the values are certainly bounded above by $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I do intend to include the possibility of sums over countable subsets of $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ (the reason I do not worry about zero is that clearly if all of the $X_n$ are zero then the sum is zero).

Comment: Certainly no $x>\pi^2/6$ can be written that way.

Comment: @zhw. Indeed, so I have revised the question. Or perhaps it makes more sense to ask if sums of the form (1) are dense in $\left[0,\frac{\pi^2}6\right)$?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Conifold.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008762/proving-that-frac-pi-2p-neq-sum-n-1-infty-frac1a-n2/1020201#1020201

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's neither discrete nor do its possible values cover the entire interval. We can essentially solve this question via the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $s_n$ be any sequence of non-negative real numbers with the property that $s_n \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}s_n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n = 0$. Then, for any $0\leq x \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}s_n$, there is some subset $S\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $x=\sum_{i\in S}s_i$.

The proof proceeds by greedily constructing $S$: we recursively define $S$ by the rule that $n\in S$ if and only if $s_n + \sum_{i\in S\cap [1,n)}s_i \leq x$. Otherwise said, we construct $S$ by enumerating the natural numbers and adding a number to $S$ if adding that element does not make the partial sum exceed the target $x$.

Clearly, $\sum_{i\in S}s_i\leq x$ since this is true, by definition, for the sum of the elements $s_i$ where $i\in S\cap [1,n]$. We can then prove that $\sum_{i\in S}s_i \geq x$ and therefore that $\sum_{i\in S}s_i = x$ by splitting into cases:

**Case 1:** $\mathbb N\setminus S$ is unbounded.

In this case, we can notice that if $n\not\in S$ we must have that
$$\sum_{i\in S}s_i \geq \sum_{i\in S\cap [1,n)}s_i > x - s_n.$$
However, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n=0$, we can conclude that $\inf \{s_n : n\not\in S\} = 0$ and then, taking suprema of both side of the above equation over all $n\not\in S$ gives
$$\sum_{i\in S}s_i \geq x$$
as desired.

**Case 2:** $S = \mathbb N$

In this case, we note that we have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}s_i \geq x$ by hypothesis, but since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} s_i = \sum_{i\in S}s_i$, we automatically have the equality we want.

**Case 3:** $\mathbb N\setminus S$ is bounded and non-empty.

We will show that this case can never occur by deriving a contradiction. Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be the largest element not in $S$. We have already seen that
$$\sum_{i\in S}s_i=\sum_{i\in S\cap [1,n)}s_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}s_i \leq x.$$
However, note that we know $s_n \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}s_i$ by hypothesis, therefore
$$\sum_{i\in S\cap [1,n)}s_i + s_n \leq x$$
by substituting in this inequality to the earlier one. This, however, would imply that $s_n \in S$ by definition of $S$, which contradicts that we chose $n$ to be in the complement of $S$. Thus, this case may never occur.

However, also note that, for any term $n$ not in $S$, we have that $\sum_{i\in S}s_i \geq \sum_{i\in S\cap [1,n)}s_i > x - s_n$.

Having handled every case, we have established the lemma.

Then, to finish, we observe that, while the sequence $s_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ fails to satisfy this property, it *does* satisfy this property if we truncate off the first term - since $\frac{1}4 \leq \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{49}$ and since, at every point further into the sequence, the ratio of consecutive terms is less than $2$. Thus, we can conclude that the set of points that can be written as $\sum_{i\in S}\frac{1}{i^2}$ is exactly $[0,\frac{\pi^2}6-1] \cup [1,\frac{\pi^2}6]$ using that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$.

---

As a side-note, it is worth noting that this doesn't imply that the distribution is *continuous* - a process such as "randomly choose the binary digits of a real number in $[0,1)$ by independent Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$" yields a distribution which has fractal-like properties and which is *not* continuous (i.e. has no probability density function) unless $p=1/2$ - it is an example of a singular distribution (with respect to the uniform distribution), which needn't be discrete. According to [Random Variables with Independent Binary Digits by Marsaglia](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240118):

> "Let $X = . b_1b_2b_3\dots$ be a random variable with independent binary digits $b_n$ taking values $0$ or $1$ with probability $p_n$ and $q_n = 1 -p_n$. When does $X$ have a density? A continuous density? A singular distribution? This
>   note gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the distribution of $X$ to be: discrete:  $\sum\min (p_n, q_n) < \infty$; singular: $\sum_m^\infty[\log (p_n/q_n)]^2=\infty$ for every $m$; absolutely continuous: $\sum_m^\infty[\log (p_n/q_n)]^2 < \infty$ for some $m$".

The example in the question truly is continuous (i.e. is defined by a probability density function) for all $p\in (0,1)$, primarily because the sequence $\frac{1}{n^2}$ does not decrease very quickly. One can prove this most easily via characteristic functions, although I would bet it's possible to prove from more elementary results such as the Berry-Esseen theorem.

Comment: I appreciate your long and detailed answer. Unfortunately, an omitted detail from my question may invalidate your conclusion of $[0,\frac{\pi^2}6-1]\cup[1,\frac{\pi^2}6]$. Please review my post for the edit - it is to allow for the extra term $x_0$ which may take value $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Math1000 The effect of adding $1$ is trivial, it just shifts the above set by $1$, so with $x_0$ you just have to take its union with that shift:$[0,\frac{\pi^2}6-1]\cup[1,\frac{\pi^2}6]\cup[2,\frac{\pi^2}6+1]$.

Comment: So is $S$ a mixture of discrete and continuous distributions, or does it have a singular continuous component?

Comment: @Math1000 After thinking on it a bit more, I can tell you that $S$ really is continuous (i.e. is defined by a probability density function), even though it can't take *every* value in $[0,\frac{\pi^2}{6}]$ - this requires some heavier machinery to prove, though. Adding a variable that can takes values in $\{0,1\}$ just creates another interval where the answer could end up in (giving three such intervals in total)

Comment: Is it because the image of $S$ is dense?

Comment: @Math1000 No, showing the existence of a probability density function is a lot more subtle than that; the distribution given by randomly choosing the binary digits of a number in $[0,1)$ from a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $2/3$, for instance, has dense image, but it can't be represented by a probability density function because, almost surely, the asymptotic density of $1$'s in the binary representation of such a number is $2/3$, but the set of numbers that satisfy this has $0$ length - so there are serious concerns beyond density for continuity.

Answer (score 3):

The sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1 \over n^2}$ is less than $1$, so if $r$ satisfies $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1 \over n^2} < r < 1$ you won't be able to express $r$ in the desired form. If you include $1$ in the sum, the result would be greater than $r$, and if you didn't include $1$ the result would be at most $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1 \over n^2} < r$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was addressed in the comments and I have suitably modified my question so that this issue was handled.

Comment: But you asked in the comments if such sums were dense in $[0,\pi^2/6]$.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't see it there.