# Find all sequences $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ of distinct positive integers such that $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Find all sequences $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ of distinct positive integers such that $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}\tag{1}.$$

This is 3rd problem from 1st day of [16-th Hungary–Israel Binational Mathematical Competition 2005](https://imomath.com/othercomp/Hi/Himc05.pdf). How to solve this?

I couldn't find official solution, only couple of posts on AoPS with no complete solution, such as [aops1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h244964p1346793) and [aops2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h141121p798082). Some examples of $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ found there are
$$
(2,3,4,5,7,12,15,20,28,35),\\
(2,3,4,6,7,9,12,14,21,36,45,60),\\
(2,3,4,5,8,10,15,20,24,30,40,60,120)
$$

Since $\sum_{i=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}<\frac{1}{2}$, we know $\frac{1}{2^2}$ will be always in the sum. Also multiplying out $(1)$ to get rid of fractions and inspecting modulo $x_i^2$, we see $2(x_1\cdots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\cdots x_n)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{x_i^2}$, so divisors of each of $x_i$ must "split" among other $x_j$'s (and $2$), but I don't think that helps much.

**Edit:** As noted by WhatsUp in comments, there is relevant problem in Project Euler. There is actually also one that is almost identical, but with limited search range, specifically https://projecteuler.net/problem=152. So it might help to think about this problem in similar manner, letting $x_n \leq M$ and then characterize solutions with these constrains. Caution, the following spoils the above mentioned Project Euler problem.

> We can convert this to more computationally manageable diophantine equation by multiplying $(1)$ by $2\text{lcm}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)^2$ instead of $2(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^2$. For example considering $\text{lcm}(2,3,4,5,7,12,15,20,28,35)=420$, first example can be written as $$420^2=2(210^2+140^2+105^2+84^2+60^2+35^2+28^2+21^2+15^2+12^2).$$ Then by the construction, all the squares on the right are divisors of the square on the left. Also, square on the left is just square of one of divisors of $\text{lcm} (2,3,\dots,M)$, if we have $M \geq 35$. This leads to following reformulation of the problem:
> Find all sequences $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n$ of distinct positive integers such that $$m^2=2(y_1^2+y_2^2+\dots+y_n^2)\tag{2},$$ where $m=\text{lcm}(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$.
> So in principle, for fixed $M$ and $x_i \leq M$, we can find $\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,M)$, and then enumerate its divisors effectively using prime factorization (using that its prime factors will be $p \leq M$). 
> Then additionally, we can notice that not all primes $p$ can be present in these numbers. Indeed, if we have $p> M/2$, then by earlier observation, it would have to divide at least two $x_i$'s. Smallest of them can be $x_i=p$, with next smallest $x_j=2p>M$, impossible. In similar way, lots of other primes can be ruled out for $M=80$, by realizing they would require to be split among at least $3$ of $x_i$'s (try $37$).
> While these ideas allow us to significantly speed up the search, it is still hard to say which factorizations will satisfy $(2)$ without actually checking the values...

Comment: In addition to requiring 2, you need either 3 or 4 since $\sum_{i=5}^{\infty} 1/i^2 < 1/4$.

Comment: This Project Euler problem is also relevant: https://projecteuler.net/problem=689

Comment: Other sequence was found.  
$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times17.$  
$[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22, 24, 33, 34, 39, 44, 51, 52, 68, 88, 102, 104, 132, 136, 143, 156, 187, 204, 221, 264, 286, 312, 374, 408, 429, 442, 561, 572, 663, 748, 858, 884, 1122, 1144, 1326, 1496, 1716, 1768, 2244, 2431, 2652, 3432, 4488, 4862, 5304, 7293, 9724, 14586, 19448, 29172, 58344]$

Comment: @WhatsUp You've reminded me of another old project euler problem which actually matches closely to this problem, I've updated the post, maybe ideas to solve that problem could lead to this (but I doubt it).

Comment: @Tomita Very nice, how the hell did you find it?

Comment: My method is same as below link's one.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h141121p798082

$(1+(\frac{1}{2})^{2})(1+(\frac{1}{3})^2)(1+(\frac{1}{4})^2)(1+(\frac{1}{11})^2)(1+(\frac{1}{13})^2)(1+(\frac{1}{17})^2)-1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1379}{736164}=(\frac{1}{26})^2+(\frac{1}{66})^2+(\frac{1}{78})^2$
Exclude $1$, $26$, $66$ and $78$ from the set all divisors of $s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times17$, then we get a solution.

Comment: Other sequence was found.  
$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times11 \times13.$  
$[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 33, 42, 44, 52, 56, 77, 78, 84, 88, 91, 104, 132, 143, 154, 156, 168, 182, 264, 273, 286, 308, 312, 364, 429, 572, 616, 728, 858, 924, 1001, 1092, 1144, 1716, 1848, 2002, 2184, 3003, 3432, 4004, 6006, 8008, 12012, 24024]$

Answer (score 5):

I found this paper:

[R.Graham, *On finite sums of unit fractions*.](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/ron/papers/64_01_unit_fractions.pdf)

One of the main corollaries of that paper says the following:

> A rational number $p/q$ can be expressed as a finite sum of reciprocals of distinct squares of integers if and only if $$\frac p q \in \left[0,\frac{\pi^2}6 - 1\right)\cup \left[1, \frac{\pi^2}6\right).$$

If this result is correct, then we may conclude that your original problem has infinitely many solutions (just repeatedly write the last term, $\frac 1{x^2}$, as $\frac 1{(x + 1)^2} + r$, where $r < \frac 1{(x + 1)^2}$ and $r$ can again be written as such a sum, by the above result).

Therefore I doubt whether there is a nice answer to this question.

There are only three possibilities:

1. The proof of Graham contains an error. I consider this unlikely, but I cannot guarantee the correctness, since I haven't thoroughly read the proof (it's quite complicated). [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction#Modern_number_theory) also cites this result.
2. The answer to this question somehow describes infinitely many solution, i.e. one should give a pattern of the solutions, rather than a finite list. This also doesn't look probable to me.
3. The question is problematic and cannot be answered properly. As it was published as a binational competition problem, it again sounds unlikely; but I think it's the most probable among the three.

I do want to know, whether the error belongs to the paper of Graham or the design of the problem. If anyone knows how to find the official solution to this problem, please do share it!

Comment: I thought about point 3. and I suspect that might be the case, though I still hope for 2. (for example some kind of pattern in terms of divisors of some arbitrary number or something). Interesting article by the way. +1

Comment: Hm similar result as in the article seems to be already on the site, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007424/finding-the-positive-integer-numbers-to-get-frac-pi-29/1007730#1007730, only it states it is for infinite sums.

Comment: @Sil That answer only writes the number as an infinite sum, which is much easier. Here we do need a finite sum.

Answer (score 1):

Other sequences were found.
My method is same as below link's one.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h141121p798082

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times17.$
\begin{align}
&(1+\frac{1}{2^2})(1+\frac{1}{3^2})(1+\frac{1}{4^2})(1+\frac{1}{11^2})(1+\frac{1}{13^2})(1+\frac{1}{17^2})-1-\frac{1}{2}\\  
&=\frac{1379}{736164}\\
&=\frac{1}{26^2}+\frac{1}{66^2}+\frac{1}{78^2}\\
\end{align}

Exclude $1$, $26$, $66$ and $78$ from the set all divisors of $s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times17$, then we get a solution.

$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22, 24, 33, 34, 39, 44, 51, 52, 68, 88, 102, 104, 132, 136, 143, 156, 187, 204, 221, 264, 286, 312, 374, 408, 429, 442, 561, 572, 663, 748, 858, 884, 1122, 1144, 1326, 1496, 1716, 1768, 2244, 2431, 2652, 3432, 4488, 4862, 5304, 7293, 9724, 14586, 19448, 29172, 58344)$

Similarly, we get below sequences.

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times11 \times13.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 33, 42, 44, 52, 56, 77, 78, 84, 88, 91, 104, 132, 143, 154, 156, 168, 182, 264, 273, 286, 308, 312, 364, 429, 572, 616, 728, 858, 924, 1001, 1092, 1144, 1716, 1848, 2002, 2184, 3003, 3432, 4004, 6006, 8008, 12012, 24024)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times17.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22, 24, 26, 34, 44, 51, 52, 68, 78, 88, 102, 104, 132, 136, 156, 187, 204, 221, 264, 312, 374, 408, 442, 561, 572, 663, 748, 884, 1122, 1144, 1326, 1496, 1716, 1768, 2244, 2431, 2652, 3432, 4488, 4862, 5304, 7293, 9724, 14586, 19448, 29172, 58344)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times11 \times19.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 19, 21, 22, 24, 28, 33, 44, 56, 76, 84, 88, 132, 133, 152, 154, 168, 209, 228, 231, 264, 266, 308, 399, 456, 532, 616, 627, 798, 836, 924, 1064, 1254, 1463, 1596, 1672, 1848, 2508, 3192, 4389, 5016, 5852, 8778, 11704, 17556, 35112)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times11 \times13 \times19.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 19, 22, 24, 26, 33, 38, 44, 52, 57, 66, 76, 88, 104, 114, 132, 143, 152, 156, 209, 228, 247, 264, 312, 418, 429, 456, 572, 627, 741, 836, 988, 1144, 1482, 1672, 1716, 1976, 2508, 2964, 3432, 5016, 5928, 8151, 10868, 21736, 32604, 65208)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times11 \times23.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 28, 33, 42, 44, 56, 69, 77, 84, 88, 92, 132, 138, 154, 161, 168, 184, 231, 253, 264, 276, 308, 462, 483, 552, 616, 644, 759, 924, 1012, 1288, 1771, 1848, 1932, 2024, 3036, 3542, 3864, 6072, 7084, 14168, 21252, 42504)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times19 \times29.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 38, 42, 56, 58, 76, 84, 114, 116, 133, 152, 168, 174, 203, 228, 232, 266, 348, 406, 456, 532, 551, 609, 696, 812, 1064, 1218, 1596, 1624, 1653, 2204, 2436, 3192, 3306, 3857, 4408, 4872, 6612, 7714, 11571, 13224, 15428, 23142, 30856, 46284, 92568)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times23 \times29.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 29, 56, 58, 69, 84, 92, 116, 138, 161, 168, 174, 184, 203, 232, 276, 348, 483, 552, 644, 667, 696, 812, 1218, 1288, 1334, 1624, 1932, 2001, 2436, 2668, 3864, 4002, 4669, 4872, 5336, 8004, 14007, 16008, 18676, 28014, 37352, 56028, 112056)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times19 \times31.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 31, 56, 57, 62, 76, 84, 114, 124, 133, 152, 168, 217, 228, 248, 266, 372, 399, 456, 532, 651, 744, 798, 868, 1064, 1596, 1736, 1767, 2356, 2604, 3192, 3534, 4123, 4712, 5208, 7068, 8246, 12369, 14136, 16492, 24738, 32984, 49476, 98952)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times29 \times31.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 31, 42, 56, 84, 87, 93, 116, 124, 168, 174, 217, 232, 248, 348, 372, 406, 434, 609, 651, 696, 744, 812, 868, 899, 1302, 1624, 1736, 1798, 2436, 2604, 2697, 3596, 4872, 5208, 5394, 6293, 7192, 10788, 21576, 25172, 50344, 75516, 151032)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times19 \times37.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 38, 42, 56, 57, 74, 76, 84, 148, 152, 168, 222, 228, 259, 266, 296, 399, 444, 456, 518, 532, 703, 777, 798, 888, 1036, 1064, 1406, 1554, 1596, 2072, 2109, 2812, 3108, 3192, 4921, 5624, 6216, 8436, 9842, 16872, 19684, 29526, 39368, 59052, 118104)$

Case :$s=2 \times3 \times4 \times7 \times23 \times37.$
$(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 24, 28, 37, 42, 56, 69, 74, 84, 92, 111, 138, 148, 161, 168, 184, 259, 276, 296, 322, 444, 483, 552, 644, 777, 888, 1036, 1288, 1554, 1702, 1932, 2072, 3108, 3404, 3864, 5106, 5957, 6216, 6808, 10212, 17871, 20424, 23828, 47656, 71484, 142968)$